# I'm not able to load my splash screen- android using VS code, can I get the steps regarding building a splash screen using Kotlin

Tags: react-native, android-splashscreen

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> com.awesomeproject.app-mergeDebugResources-34:/values/values.xml:2109: error: resource drawable/rn_edit_text_material (aka com.awesomeproject:drawable/rn_edit_text_material) not found.
> com.awesomeproject.app-mergeDebugResources-34:/values/values.xml:2109: error: resource drawable/rn_edit_text_material (aka com.awesomeproject:drawable/rn_edit_text_material) not found.
> error: failed linking references.

These errors are appearing when I try to install my app.

The splash screen is not appearing. There are several splash screens that I modified for several android screens. How can I give the location of specifically one?